# Barnard's exact tests - papers?

Tags: references, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, exact-test

I am currently writing some essay for the university in which I should give a quick overview over exact methods for independence testing on contingency tables, after writing down the stuff for Fisher's exact test I wanted to give an example for an unconditional test but I find almost nothing to the test itself ? Do you have any paper or site which explains the barnard test in a simple manner ?